# Can't seem to get high-voltage source driver (TD62783APG) working

Tags: driver, current-source

I'm trying to power 12 V DC motors using a high-voltage source driver ([TD62783APG](https://www.digchip.com/datasheets/download_datasheet.php?id=1481927&part-number=TD62783APG) or [UDN2981](https://media.digikey.com/pdf/Data%20Sheets/Allegro%20PDFs/2981_2982_Rev2012.pdf)).

[image]

I made a small test project with a 5 V power supply and a single LED.

I thought that when driving I2 high output 2 would get the voltage of V<sub>CC</sub>. But I can't figure out why it's not working. The IC is getting very hot and seems to short-circuit.

[image: Test circuit]

What mistake am I making with this circuit?

Comment: DCR of Motor and Voh @Imax makes a big difference with these ICs rated for high voltage and low current.  Wrong application it seems.

Answer (score 1):

1. Vcc must be powered not switched from logic.
2. The IC was damaged. Perhaps from using a motor then switched off from flyback with this method badly connecting logic input to Vcc.
3. The driver is rated for 500mA but not all at one time, resistive, not inductive as motors have a resistance 10x lower than rated V/I.
4. This may work Ok for a tiny 100mA motor only, consider a low side Nch FET with RdsOn much lower than motor coil DCR

Answer (score 0):

Hard to know why the part is hot.  Try connecting only VCC and Ground.  If hot then.... pad part, VCC<>Ground are backwards, wrong part, fake part, .... should not be hot.